# EC2 instance keeps respawning, even after termination

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

A quite annoying EC2 instance keeps respawning, no matter how many times I try to delete or terminate it.

What could be the cause of this? How can I finally get rid of this Micro testing instance?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems likely that this instance was started within an Auto Scaling Group, possibly as part of an Elastic Beanstalk deployment. If this is the case, either delete the Elastic Beanstalk deployment or set the min and max sizes for the ASG to 0 and this instance will go away.

Comment: Definitely an Elastic Beanstalk deployment - the security group is prefixed with "awseb" in the screenshot. +1 for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Ahh, good eye.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do it. Still getting my head around this whole ecosystem, having come from dedicated environments.